# R Regex Problem: "-\\s[A-Z]" Lowercase the matched uppercase letter and delete dash+whitespace

Tags: r, regex, replace, match

Suppose you have a string: "Stack- Overflow"

I want to lowercase the uppercase character which is preceded by dash and space and delete the dash and space.

So far i was able to match the pattern using a regex. But how can i lowercase that character without doing that manually?

```
c("Stack- Overflow") %>% str_replace_all("-\\s[A-Z]", "o")
```

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 5):

You may use `gsub` with `perl=TRUE` like this:

```
c("Stack- Overflow") %>% gsub(pattern="-\\s+([A-Z])", replacement="\\L\\1", perl=TRUE)
[1] "Stackoverflow"
```

**Details**

- `-` - matches a hyphen
- `\\s+` - 1 or more whitespaces
- `([A-Z])` - Capturing group 1: any ASCII uppercase letter

The `\\L` is the lowercase operator that turns all the text to the right of it lowercase until `\\E` operator is encountered (here, it is omitted since the whole replacement text must be turned to lower case).

Comment: You're my hero if the day. Thanks so much! :)

Comment: Just FYI: to match any uppercase letters, use `gsub(pattern="-\\s(\\p{Lu})", replacement="\\L\\1", perl=TRUE)`